# Options for an inexpensive short stay near Tempe, AZ, USA

Tags: usa, accommodation

I am admitted to a university near Tempe, AZ and have booked my flight for July 31st. The problem is the apartments are available for lease only from August 8th. What are my options to have an inexpensive temporary stay before I move into the apartment? I am also concerned about the safety of myself and my property.

Comment: AirBnB? Short stay apartment?

Comment: Motels, Hotels, Camping, renting a car and sleeping in designated camping spots?

Comment: @Berwyn But, still, the question is massively broad and opinion-based. "Places to stay in the US", even when restricted to _types_ of accommodation, is a huge subject.

Comment: @DavidRicherby These weren't closed: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/options-for-cheap-private-month-long-stay-in-munich http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/65410/find-short-term-room-in-the-u-s-from-abroad http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13597/what-are-my-unreserved-accommodation-options-when-doing-a-road-trip-in-the-us

Comment: @Berwyn One of them is specific to one town; the other is asking for advice specific to small children. Neither of them is "What kinds of accommodation exist?"

Comment: One thing that's worth mentioning is that typically the university can generally take care of this sort of thing for you. Universities are aware of foreign students attending and have either in-house housing or deals with local hotels for such stays.

If you haven't - by all means contact the university. The answer touches this but it should be your get-go.

Comment: @Kenpachi Please see Dorothy's comment to my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The options for inexpensive short stays near Tempe, AZ include:

- [airbnb](https://www.airbnb.com/)
- [Budget hotel chains](http://www.10best.com/awards/travel/best-budget-hotel-brand/) like [Red Roof Inns](https://www.redroof.com/) or [Best Western](http://www.bestwestern.com/reservations/hotels/united-states.asp)
- [Couch Surfing](https://www.couchsurfing.com/)
- [Hostels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostelling_International_USA)

There may be alternative academic housing if you contact the university.

Also see [this site](http://www.independenttraveler.com/travel-tips/hotel-and-b-and-b/ditch-the-hotel-10-cheaper-ways-to-stay) for a few more esoteric ideas like farmstays and monesteries.

Safest will most likely be a hotel.

Comment: Tempe is within metro Phoenix, where there's a great hostel, the Phoenix Hostel and Cultural Center at 1026 North 9th Street. It does have private rooms with key-code locks, as well as luggage storage.  http://phxhostel.org/

Comment: @Dorothy That looks great